# Grouping images together according to their foreign key id in php

Tags: php, html, sql

so I have a carousel which I need it to be repeated according to the number of images grouped together , so what i mean is that i have table called **multipleimg** which takes a foreign key from table called **apartemenntinfo** , so when i insert the data succesfuly in both tables but i want to display each group of images together in a carousel so each time i insert new collection of images , a carousel should appears with this new images grouped together with their id , i had tried this code but it's not working

```
  <article class="games row  ">
                <?php
                $q = "SELECT apartementinfo.Aid ,multipleimg.iid , apartementinfo.description, multipleimg.img FROM apartementinfo 
                inner JOIN multipleimg
                ON multipleimg.Aid = apartementinfo.Aid 
                 ; ";

                $result = $conn->query($q);
                foreach ($result as $r) { ?>
                

                    <div class="game col-4 ">

                        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                            
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img src="<?=$r['img']?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php } ?>

            </article>
```

and here is the schema of both tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `apartementinfo` (
`Aid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Rid` int(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Aid`),
 KEY `Rid` (`Rid`),
 CONSTRAINT `apartementinfo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Rid`) REFERENCES `resident` (`Rid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4


CREATE TABLE `multipleimg` (
`iid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`img` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Aid` int(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`iid`),
 KEY `Aid` (`Aid`),
 CONSTRAINT `multipleimg_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Aid`) REFERENCES `apartementinfo` (`Aid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

so any idea how to do this ??

Comment: any help ??????

Comment: Not quite clear. Try to split your problem into several smaller tasks.

Comment: I have a group of images , I want to display each group of them in different carousels  grouped together by their post id  , that's it !!